# Where in the USA can I experience this particular accent?

Tags: usa

**Update**: Reposted to english.stackexchange.com: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369004/which-american-accent-is-this

A common theme I've noticed in many "big-beat" songs and the electronic genre, especially songs by British artists, is to use voice-samples of a particular American accent, or imitiate the accent if the music artist is doing their own vocals.

An example of it can be heard in this Underworld song "Push Downstairs":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lR0vEUrEYY (from time 1:01)

I have a personal mental association of the accent with 1970s Vegas culture: I visualize a thin (not overweight) MC at a mid-market casino or event wearing a 10-gallon hat and bola-tie and sideburns talking with this accent (e.g. like [Bob from *Bob's RV Roundup*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuM0f.jpg). This mental association might be from someone I saw on TV that spoke like this ([Bob himself sounds almost similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_gFj11nX-g), I note - but I wouldn't describe it as a "cowboy accent").

Having been to Vegas in person, and as a 4-year resident of the US West Coast, I can't say I've ever heard this accent spoken by a person in real-life.

So where is it from? Is it a real accent or a fake accent created by the media industry like the Mid-Atlantic accent?

Comment: It appears to be an affectation, but to identify accents you need a clear spoken recording -- without the music and singing.... Minded to mark as 'unclear' or 'off-topic', please try over on http://english.stackexchange.com/ where your question (which I like by the way) may be received better.